# Formtastic in JavaScript (form builder)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, spine.js

Are you aware of any form builders that do similar job to [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) but in the browser?

It should not be very heavy (so not ExtJS) and ideally compatible with structure that Formtastic generates, jQuery based and HAML-JS friendly.

The purpose is to make it easier to create forms with SpineJS for Rails.

Under easier I mean:

- no need to add hidden fields to act as "unchecked";
- no need to repeat same structure all over again;
- no need to manually add classes to all the elements;
- produce inline-errors;
- etc;

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your answer in a long shot, but I was looking for something similar a couple of days ago. Although I ideally want my client-side form-builder to be based on JSON instead of what you describe. The advantage of that would be the possibility to BOTH do client-side as server-side form-building from the same source (tis staying DRY). Anyway, the closest I got was https://github.com/neyric/inputex, which builds forms based on JSON but relies on YUI.  It might help you in some way

Comment: Actually, you're question got me searching again as I still have the same problem. I've found this active project..http://neyeon.com/2011/01/creating-forms-with-json-and-jquery/.. Based on JSON though..

Comment: Thanks for that. But it looks like inputEx is a "clone" of ExtJS inputs. Not really a form builder. But the jQuery dForm looks interesting.

Comment: dForm looks interesting indeed. Are you able to hook it up with spine.js?

Answer (score 6):

This is for Backbone and not Spine, but it's pretty much what you want: https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at using Jotform, or foxyform?

Comment: I don't think you've read the question. Those are *user* tools that help humans to create online forms. I am looking for *developer* tools that would help build the HTML form JS.